# html2text: How to parse urls containing special characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, encoding

I'm trying to use Aaron Swartz's Python [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) library (on Python 2.7). I haven't succeeded at using html2text() on strings containing a link whose URL has a special character. For example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import html2text
s = u'Link <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Málaga">here</a>!'
str = html2text.html2text(s)
```

Fails with error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Whereas:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import html2text
s = u'<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaga">héré</a>!'
str = html2text.html2text(s)
```

(which has special characters, but only in text, not in the URL) works just fine.

I must be missing something with the encoding, but I can't find anything in the documentation. Is there a way of telling html2text to use a non-ascii encoder in its url parser?

Comment: Where are those URL-like strings coming from? Non-ascii characters aren't valid in URLs, so the question is whether you have bad input that you need to tolerate anyway or whether you're accidentally unescaping a valid URI somewhere, like the `<link rel="canonical" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1laga"/>` version on that page.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Bad input that needs to be tolerated! An automatic conversion to the canonical version would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode non-ascii characters with [`urllib.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) (`urllib.parse.quote` in Python3).  The charecters specified in the `safe` parameter will not be encoded.

```
import html2text
from urllib import quote

s = 'Link <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Málaga">here</a>!'
q = quote(s, safe=' <>="/:!')
s = html2text.html2text(q)

print q
print s

Link <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1laga">here</a>!
Link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1laga)!
```

---

You can't have unicode characters in href because it is formatted in string.
The error comes from `html2text.HTML2Text.close` in line 163 : `outtext = nochr.join(self.outtextlist)`, where `nochr` is `unicode('')`, and `self.outtextlist` is a list of the tag parts:

```
[u'Link ', '[', u'h\xe9r\xe9', '](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mlaga)', u'!', '\n', '']
```

As you can see the item containing the href is not a unicode string.

That's because in `html2text.HTML2Text.handle_tag`, in function `link_url`, line 440, url is formated to string: `']({url}{title})'.format(url=escape_md(url), title=title)`.
If you change it to unicode (`u']({url}{title})'`) you'll get a unicode string in `self.outtextlist`:

```
[u'Link ', '[', u'h\xe9r\xe9', u'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ml\xe1ga)', u'!', '\n','']
```

and the output with `u'Link <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mlága">héré</a>!'` will be:

```
Link [héré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mlága)!
```

However i don't recommend modifying the original code. A possible solution would be to subclass `HTML2Text` and overwrite `link_url`, but the problem is that `link_url` is a local function, so you would have to overwrite the entire `handle_tag` method.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed insight t.m. adam! I made it work using quote and a regex for finding URLs. Strangely, I seem to have a backup of a file for which html2text processed correctly a "problematic" url. In any case, this works, so thank you :)